# Canter - Clarification of Meaning?

Tags: meaning

[Merriam Webster's](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/canter) first definition of canter states:

> One who uses cant, such as:
> a : beggar, vagabond
> b : a user of professional or religious cant

I get the meaning of a, but I'm at a loss for the b definition. I didn't know "cant" was something that could be used. Can anyone explain what they mean by this??

Comment: Did you look up *cant* while you were on M-W? Do so, and scroll down to the 6th definition.

Comment: I don’t understand what’s unclear. _Cant_ is “language specific to a particular group or profession” ([ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/cant)); why would language not be something that can be used? Can you clarify what exactly it is you find difficult to understand?

Comment: @StoneyB Ah, no I didn't. For some reason I just had it in my head as can't, I didn't even realize it was a different word. So I was thinking that for a: that they just "can't". My brain clearly isn't working this morning. Thanks.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet see above. Apparently I "can't" even think clearly morning. Thank you for posing your thoughts/questions in positive way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"[Cant](https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=cant&oq=cant&aqs=chrome..69i57.783j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)" is a particular style of speech, usually "hypocritical and sanctimonious talk, typically of a moral, religious, or political nature." but it may also be applied to professional jargon in some circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

Under the 6th definition of Cant (noun), Merriam Webster states:

> Definition of cant
>
> 1: affected singsong or whining speech; a beggar's cant
>
> 2a : the private language of the underworld; the cant of thieves
>
> b obsolete : the phraseology peculiar to a religious class or sect

So it seems that religious cant is an obsolete noun.

(First answer on this site, hope it helps)

Answer (score 0):

"Cant" is pretty rare, and "canter", while a clear derivation, I can't imagine being useful more than say, once in a hundred years.

"Cantor", of course, is something else entirely (just in case that's what you were looking for).  Cantors use cant only incidentally.